# Confirm heterogeneity in a fish population over time

Tags: population, heterogeneity

For my thesis I have to statistically prove that heterogeneity is establishing over time, more specific in the weights of a fish population.

My dataset consists out of the weights of 17fish and the 10 different dates when these the measurements were taken.

I don't really have an idea how to begin. On every date 17fish are measured that should follow a normal distribution. This gives a standard deviation that I expect to enlarge in the following measurements over time.

Could somebody help me in which way I should start to think to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Lien

Comment: Could you elaborate on the form of heterogeneity that you are referring to? Do you expect the fish to have ever more distant weights, like (5,5,5) for today, then (5,6,7) for tomorrow, then (5,7,9) for two days from now etc. if your have three fish measured over time (I know you have 17 fish, not three, but it's just an example)? That will matter in constructing a model or a test.